# installation of bootstrap-table not working properly with rails 6, webpack and bootstrap5, it sets bootstra4 version on table instead

Tags: webpack, ruby-on-rails-6, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-table

### What I have done

I have a project where bootstrap5 is working properly. I tried to install bootstrap-table with

`yarn add bootstrap-table`

in `application.js` I got:

```
import 'bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js'
import 'bootstrap-table/dist/locale/bootstrap-table-de-DE.min.js'
```

and in backend.sass:

```
@import '~bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css'
```

### Details

jquery was added with yarn and is v3.6.0 and I have first

`import $ from 'jquery'` in `application.js`

and in `environment.js`:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const coffee = require('./loaders/coffee')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
  jquery: 'jquery',
  'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}))
```

### Problem

so now the styles are not applied correctly and it applies bootstrap4 to the table class:

[image]

When I enter bootstrap5 instead the style is correclty applied, elsewise not.
Also the Dropdown for pagination is not working. When I click on it nothing pops up.
The normal dropdown from bootstrap5 is working by itself outside of bootstrap-table.

### What I tried

I have tried to change imports a lot, installed different yarn packages.
I found [this issue](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/5837) on the github repo. Adding the constant in `application.js` is not working for me.

They wrote the bootstrap version would be read out in `index.js` likewise:

```
let bootstrapVersion = 4

try {
  const rawVersion = $.fn.dropdown.Constructor.VERSION

  // Only try to parse VERSION if it is defined.
  // It is undefined in older versions of Bootstrap (tested with 3.1.1).
  if (rawVersion !== undefined) {
    bootstrapVersion = parseInt(rawVersion, 10)
  }
```

for some reason `$.fn.dropdown.Constructor` is undefined for me. Tried to change imports to fix this, but not sure why it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check answers provided here https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/5837#issuecomment-952301379

helped to solve the issue the following way:

```js
// bootstrap.js
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'
window.bootstrap = {
  Tooltip: {
    VERSION: "5"
  }
}
```

instead import the new bootstrap.js BEFORE importing Bootstrap Table in `application.js` For example:

```js
import '../assets/js/bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.js'
import 'bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css'
```

the file has probably to be included since webpacker may change the code execution after imports if you try to add `window.bootstrap ...` within `application.js`